# Need help with mootools slide down header

Tags: jquery, mootools

Im trying to figure out mootools. What I need is a div which is placed at the top of the page to slide down and wait a few seconds and then slide back up.

Jquery code  for this looks like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('#headerdiv').delay(3500).slideToggle(600).delay(20000).slideToggle(600);
});
```

The reason I wont use Jquery is because there are a lot of things using mootools and I had trouble trying to load Jquery with mootools.

Thanks

Comment: Btw. Including multiple frameworks on one page is the worst thing you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/fVddg/

```
var slider = document.id('slider');

var myFx = new Fx.Slide(slider, {
    link: 'chain'
});

myFx.hide();
myFx.slideIn();
myFx.slideOut.delay(1000, myFx);
```